# How to work with KotlinX serialization for ArrayList<String> and Date types with Algolia

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.serialization, instantsearch, instantsearch-android

I am trying to use the `kotlinx serialization` with Algolia for types `ArrayList<String>` and `Date` but I cannot figure out the `serialization` technique. Any pointers because I have resorted to the manual way that is not recommended by `Algolia`.

Answer (score 1):

> Check this one
>
> [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/custom_serializers.md)

```
import kotlinx.serialization.*
import kotlinx.serialization.internal.*
import java.util.*

@Serializable
class DateWrapper(val date: Date)

@Serializer(forClass = Date::class)
object DateSerializer: KSerializer<Date> {
    private val df: DateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss.SSS")

    override fun save(output: KOutput, obj: Date) {
        output.writeStringValue(df.format(obj))
    }

    override fun load(input: KInput): Date {
        return df.parse(input.readStringValue())
    }

    override val serialClassDesc: KSerialClassDesc = SerialClassDescImpl("Date")
}
```

> Register it at startup of your application:

```
kotlinx.serialization.registerSerializer("java.util.Date", DateSerializer)
```

`JSON.stringify(DateWrapper(Date()))` will give you {"date":["Date","10/11/2019 12:50:10.665"]}